# jQuery data received from server does not keep original format using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am receiving data from the server and displaying it to the user. I originally was displaying the data using a `textarea` and all the formatting is correct (line breaks, tabs...etc).

html:

```
<textarea id="textArea" class="textArea" readonly></textarea>
```

js:

```
//data stream received from server
...
data = xhr.responseText;
$( ".textArea" ).val( data );
```

The above works fine, however, now I want to switch my `textarea` to a `div` instead (to add styles and be able to print the div later...), but after I switched all my formatting received from the server are gone and all the data is displayed in a whole blob when I use append:

html:

```
<div id="textArea" class="textArea"></div>
```

js:

```
//data stream received from server
...
data = xhr.responseText;
$(".textArea").append(data);
```

How can I keep the source formatting when appending data to `div`?

Comment: Can you use `<pre>`? Or add `white-space: pre;` to the `<div>`.

Comment: @azeós you mean like this `$(".textArea").append(<pre>data</pre>); ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really looking for is a way to make a `div` behave like a `textarea`, because a `textarea` renders text in a fixed-width font and remembers whitespace.

```
.textarea {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-family: monospace;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AnonymousSB/hkfy14es/

Note: Unlike a `textarea`, you have to keep the first line of text on the same line as your opening `div` element to prevent a gap at the top, because `white-space: pre;` makes it render ALL white space.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for.